# Assigning a shortcut to Visual Assist's quick actions

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-assist

In plain Visual Studio there is the `Alt+Enter` shortcut, which brings up a popup with  quick fixes and improvement suggestions.

I am using the [Visual Assist](https://wholetomato.com/) plugin for c++ development, which lets me right-click on a item and open 'Quick Actions and Refactorings (VA)' menu.

I would like to combine these two options into one: Having the advanced features in the easy accessible `Alt+Enter` shortcut without reaching to the mouse and right-click. Anyone knows how to assign a custom shortcut to 'Quick Actions and Refactoring'? Or any suggestions how to get rid of the tedious right-click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigning shortcuts always works like this in Visual Studio:
`Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard`

1. Find the right identifier for the desired action, which is
   `VAssistX.RefactorContextMenu` in your case.
2. Assign the desired shortcut `Alt+Enter` for the scope `Text Editor` and there you go.

Note, that this replaces Visual Studio's original Alt+Enter functionality, not blending them together.